# Group by days of a month in CockroachDB

Tags: sql, cockroachdb

In CockroachDB, I want to have such this query on a specific month for its every day:

```
select count(*), sum(amount) 
from request
where code = 'code_string' 
and created_at >= '2022-07-31T20:30:00Z' and created_at < '2022-08-31T20:30:00Z'
```

the problem is that I want it on my local date. What should I do?
My goal is:

"month, day, count, sum" as result columns for a month.

---

UPDATE:

I have found a suitable query for this purpose:

```
select count(amount), sum(amount), extract(month from created_at) as monthTime, extract(day from created_at) as dayTime 
from request 
where code = 'code_string' and created_at >= '2022-07-31T20:30:00Z' and created_at < '2022-08-31T20:30:00Z'
group by dayTime, monthTime
```

Thanks to @histocrat for easier answer :) by replacing

```
extract(month from created_at) as monthTime, extract(day from created_at) as dayTime
```

by this:

```
date_part('month', created_at) as monthTime, date_part('day', created_at) as dayTime
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To group results by both month and day, you can use the [date_part](https://www.cockroachlabs.com/docs/stable/functions-and-operators.html#date-and-time-functions) function.

```sql
select month, day, count(*), sum(things)
from request
where code = 'code_string'
group by date_part('month', created_at) as month, date_part('day', created_at) as day;
```

Depending on what type `created_at` is, you may need to cast or convert it first (for example, `group by date_part('month', created_at::timestamptz)`).